# Querying value from JSON field in Flask-SQLAlchemy with postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and postgresql with JSON field types.
I am having issues querying data out using SQLAlchemy

Here is my model example:

```
class WorkQueue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "workQueue"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    field_data = db.Column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, field_data = None):
        self.field_data = field_data
```

Here is an example of the dataset I am committing to the database

```
{
    "files": 
    [
        {
            "added": 1470248644.093014, 
            "totalbytes": 1109630458,  
            "filename": "/home/me/project/static/uploads/file.ext", 
            "finished": false,
            "basefilename": "file.ext",
            "file_id": 21, 
            "numsegments": 2792
        }
     ],
     "numfiles": 1,
     "success": true
}
```

I am having issues querying - trying to find "WorkQueue['files'][0]['file_id']" from a route defined as such:

```
@page.route('/remove/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_remove(id):
    to_remove = id

    # here is where I would query and delete, but I can't get this right
```

From psql it would be something like this:

```
select * from "workQueue" t, json_array_elements(t.field_data->'files') as files WHERE CAST(files->>'file_id' AS INTEGER) = 1;
```

Just cannot seem to replicate that in SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

something like this

```
from sqlalchemy import func, Integer

files_subquery = session.query(func.json_array_elements(WorkQueue.field_data['files']).label('files')) \
                        .subquery()
query = session.query(WorkQueue.id, WorkQueue.field_data, files_subquery.c.files) \
               .filter(files_subquery.c.files.op('->>')('file_id').cast(Integer) == 1)
```

Comment: Perfectly illustrated what I'm asking for.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: This answer deserves more than two up-votes. Digged out all of the documentations but couldn't figure out how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! :)